Find: $ \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(x) \cos(t)}{(b^2 - a^2 \sin^2(x))(1 + \sin^2(t) \cos^2(x))} \ dt \ dx $

Question

Find:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(x) \cos(t)}{(b^2 - a^2 \sin^2(x))(1 + \sin^2(t) \cos^2(x))} \, dt \, dx
$$
for $a, b \neq 0$.

My attempt

\begin{align}
I_{a,b} = &\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2(x) \cos(t)}{(b^2 - a^2 \sin^2(x))\left(1 + \sin^2(t) \cos^2(x)\right)} \, dt \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{b^2 - a^2 \sin^2(x)} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(t)}{\left(1 + \cos(x) \sin(t)\right)^2} \, dt \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{b^2 - a^2 \sin^2(x)} \left[ \tan^{-1} \left( \cos(x) \sin(t) \right) \right]_0^{\pi/2} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x) \arctan(\cos(x))}{b^2 - a^2 \sin^2(x)} \
dx
\end{align}
This is what I was barely able to do. Now, I'm not sure what to do next—perhaps integration by parts?
Can someone provide the closed form for different values of $a$ and $b$?

Too bad the "1+" is standing in the way of an obvious factorization into separate $t$ and $x$ integrals.

Why downvote??????

Let
$$J(t)= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x\tan^{-1}(\tan t\cos x)}{1-\sin^2s\sin^2x}dx
$$
along with
\begin{align}
J’(t)=& \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2s\sec^2t\cos^2x}{(1+\tan^2s\cos^2x) (1+\tan^2t\cos^2x) }dx
= \frac{\frac\pi2}{\cos t+\cos s}
\end{align}
Then, set $\sin s=\frac ab$ to evaluate
\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x\tan^{-1}(\cos x)}{b^2-a^2\sin^2x}dx\\
= &\ \frac1{b^2} \int_0^{\pi/4}J’(t)dt = \frac{\pi}{2b^2}\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac1{\cos t+\cos s}dt\\
 = &\ \frac\pi{b^2\sin s}\tanh^{-1}\bigg(\tan\frac s2\tan\frac t2\bigg)\bigg|_0^{\frac\pi4} \\
= &\ \frac\pi{ab}\tanh^{-1}\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{(\sqrt2+1)a}
\end{align}

Assuming $0<a<b$, introduce and differentiate w.r.t. a parameter $k\in\Bbb R$:
$$\begin{align*}
J(k) &= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\cos x}{b^2-a^2\sin^2x} \arctan(k \cos x) \, dx \\[2ex]
J'(k) &= \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\cos^2x}{\left(1+k^2\cos^2x\right) \left(b^2-a^2\sin^2x\right)} \, dx \\
&= \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+\left(a^2-b^2\right)k^2} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dx}{b^2-a^2\sin^2x} \\
&\qquad + \frac1{a^2+\left(a^2-b^2\right)k^2} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{dx}{1+k^2\cos^2x} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2\left(a^2+\left(a^2-b^2\right)k^2\right)} \left[ \frac1{\sqrt{1+k^2}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}}\right]
\end{align*}$$
Now use $J(0)=0$ and integrate to recover the integral we want,
$$J(1) = \frac\pi2 \int_0^1 \frac{dk}{\left(a^2+\left(a^2-b^2\right)k^2\right)} \left[\frac1{\sqrt{1+k^2}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}}\right]$$
which is susceptible to Euler's substitution.
We end up finding (some tedious details omitted)
$$\begin{align*}
I(a,b)&=\frac\pi{2ab} \left(\tanh^{-1}\frac b{\sqrt2\,a} - \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1}\right) \\
&= \boxed{\frac\pi{2ab} \tanh^{-1} \frac a{\sqrt2\,b+\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}}
\end{align*}$$

The last equality is questionable $$\tanh^{-1}\frac b{\sqrt2,a} - \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}-1}
\ne \tanh^{-1} \frac a{\sqrt2,b+\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}$$

@Quanto Mathematica disagrees but WA being WA, I won't rule out the possibility of a false positive. However, there does seem to be a lot of numerical evidence that it does hold, at least for the sample space I checked $(0<a<b<10^2)$; see this notebook

I mean, for certain a and b, the lhs is only defined in complex domain
